# I want an "hover" function so that my android box (controlled by a remote) can display the selected option

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is my code , but i can´t seem to make it as to where the selected option pops out so the user can see what option is selected , also from the looks of it there isnt a hover function in react native , i am using a remote for an android box in a tv and the user needs to see what option is selected.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

const LandingPage = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [hoveredItem, setHoveredItem] = useState(null);

  


  const [items] = useState([
    { title: 'Channels', key: 'Channels' },
    { title: 'Movies', key: 'Movies' },
    { title: 'Messages', key: 'Messages' },
    { title: 'Map', key: 'Map' },
    { title: 'Weather', key: 'Weather' },
    { title: 'Language', key: 'Language' },
    /* { title: 'Web', key: 'WebView' }*/

  ]);

  const handleItemHover = (itemKey) => {
    setHoveredItem(itemKey);
  };

  const handleItemUnhover = () => {
    setHoveredItem(null);
  };


  const handleItemPress = (item) => {
    navigation.navigate(`${item}Page`);

  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0.9 }}
        end={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
        colors={['#00050a', '#000000']}

      >

        <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/cruzeiro.png')} style={styles.image}>


          <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Amadouro</Text>
            <Text style={styles.title2}>103</Text>

          </View>
          <ScrollView
            style={styles.scrollView}
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContent}
          >
            {items.map((item) => (
                <TouchableHighlight
                  key={item.key}
                  style={[
                    styles.touchable,
                    { backgroundColor: hoveredItem === item.key ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)' : 'transparent' },
                  ]}
                  activeOpacity={0.8}
                  onPress={() => handleItemPress(item.key)}
                  onPressIn={handleItemHover}
                  onPressOut={handleItemUnhover}
                >
                  <LinearGradient
                    colors={['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)']}
                    start={{ x: 0.6, y: 0.1 }}
                    end={{ x: 0.1, y: 0.9 }}
                    style={[styles.item, styles[item.key.toLowerCase()],
                    ]}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.title}</Text>
                  </LinearGradient>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        </ImageBackground>
      </LinearGradient>

    </View>
  );
};
```

I tried implementing an animation but that didn´t work to be fair so im lost.

Answer (score 0):

To archive this consider using the `Pressable` component instead of `TouchableHighlight`. While I haven't tested it on a TV, it should work for your use case. Here's the updated code:

```
              <Pressable
                key={item.key}
                style={({ pressed }) => [
                  styles.touchable,
                  {
                    backgroundColor: pressed ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)' : focusedItem === item.key ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)' : 'transparent',
                  },
                ]}
                onPress={() => handleItemPress(item.key)}
                onPressIn={handleItemHover}
                onPressOut={handleItemUnhover}
              >
                <LinearGradient
                  colors={['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)']}
                  start={{ x: 0.6, y: 0.1 }}
                  end={{ x: 0.1, y: 0.9 }}
                  style={[styles.item, styles[item.key.toLowerCase()]]}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.title}</Text>
                </LinearGradient>
              </Pressable>
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: hey , thank you! But the focused item doesn´t exist , what should i do with it?

Comment: Here i am again , i replaced focusedItem with hoveredItem in my useState and the result is the same , the remote doesn´t recognize that toggle as a press i dont know what else to do

Comment: can you try the `onHoverIn` instead of `onPressIn `

Comment: it still doesn´t work , i dont know what the remote is sending to the box and even with the mouse the onHoverIn doesn´t work the only thing that works is if i press the button and dont let it go

Comment: That's wired I'll make some search and I'll post an update

Comment: Please do i am desperate LOL